# How does dolphindb specify column names like MySQL when inserting data？

Tags: mysql, dolphindb

I have a table with hundreds of lines, and I just want insert some column data, and how to specify column name, in mysql I can write

```
insert into joke (gid,name)value(0,”joker”);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible and also unnecessary

Insert new records to a table.

> Syntax:

```
insert into

   table_name1

   values (X, [Y], ...) | select col_name(s) from table_name2
```

[Online manual for INSERT INTO](https://www.dolphindb.cn/en/help/index.html?append1.html)